# How to sync branch's to master which shouldn't be merged with master?

Tags: git, github, git-merge

In my repository I have 5 more branches other than master. Master branch hold some generic code and other 5 branches have customized code built upon the master's branch, the master branch need to update time to time and I want to update all other branches with master without loosing any customized code which is local to those branches and I also don't want any branch to merge back to master, how can I do this please explain your answer thanks.

Comment: Why not merge master into the other branches?

Comment: Sorry I am new to git. Can I merge master into all 5 branches? @mkrieger1

Comment: Yes, you can do that.

Comment: Can you please provide me a link or something that explains how can I do this? Thanks

Comment: You mean, like, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging?

Answer (score 0):

You could merge main into your desire branch `main -> branch` on your Github repository page instead of the typical `branch -> main`

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ScGy6.png)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for something like this :

```sh
git checkout your-branch
git rebase master
```

In particular, the second command will update "your-branch" with master without altering master

Comment: Personally I prefer the `git merge --no-ff master` way as I like a commit to indicate when and from where I merge changes for the branch.